# how to get automatic converted 'echo' of php from html code?

Tags: php, html, echo

I would like to easy to get converted code that 'echo' of php code from html code.

For example, Just like this. 
http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

This is a convert tool for JS printing code from html.

Conclude, I would like to see below

from

```
<div id="foo">
 <div id="bar">
 </div>
</div>
```

to

```
echo '<div id="foo">';
 echo '<div id="bar">';
 echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Thank you for read.

Comment: Hi! What did you try yet? Did you have a look to the php documentation?

Comment: HI! I know but i'm just finding a converting tool. Is there about like this tool in the php doc?

Comment: Ok, I thought you were trying to write a code, and not that you were searching for one. Maybe you could clarify your request then. As of me, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can echo multiple lines of text like this:

```
echo <<< EOT
<div id="foo">
<div id="bar">
</div>
</div>
EOT;
```

Comment: Just a note to this, do not put a space infront of EOT; as it then will be considered as part of your string.